# Using the URLconf defined in myapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order

Tags: django

I think I went through every available answer to this error but they all reference some other tutorial and a views.py which I do not have. After running the tutorial from [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-on-linux-shared-hosting) I get this 404 error.

```
Using the URLconf defined in myapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    ^$ [name='home']
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^static/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, market_data/, didn’t match any of these.
```

The urls.py has the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import re_path as url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='templates/static_pages/index.html'), name='home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The root directory structure of this project is

```
~/market_data/myapp
~/market_data/myapp/static_media
~/market_data/myapp/static_files
~/market_data/myapp/static_files/admin
~/market_data/myapp/templates
~/market_data/myapp/templates/static_pages
```

Thank you for any tips!

Comment: Do you have index.html or home.html in your templates?

Comment: What url did you type into your browser?

Comment: there is index.html in the templates